# Windows 2008 Server online diagnostics

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

I've got a server that runs some web services and a web site. We are going to go for alpha and beta testing soon and would like to test the load on the server - i.e check the latency, response times and etc.

Is there any way of doing so live during the alpha/beta testing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say load testing, which implies simulating many concurrent connections to see how the server can handle heavy use, so for just single user latency, reponse, etc. without buying expensive tools I love Google Chrome's built in element inspector.

But I'm not a "real" developer and your question would be much better served by developers who do this as a part of their standard work processes over at stackoverflow.com